# How to modify current RequestHeader in playframework2?

Tags: scala, session, cookies, playframework-2.0, request-headers

In playframework 2, the session and cookie is modified available in next session but not current session.

like code:

Ok(views.html.something("Hello from Scala")).withSession(("user"->"Admin"))

this session will be modified and presented in next session. Can I made some Cookie which can available in current session?

I do not want to use parameter to modify it for the reason is if I use parameter as user login and role indentified Tag, it would be added all page control parameters table. I want to do it as an AOP, injected in session and then only look at session to find out the request come from where and how to response it in template frame not in content.
Any one have better solution for this issue are also welcome to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play's session is a client-side session stored in a cookie, and sent to the client with every response. Since you can only modify the session when you actually answer, any changes you want to make use of in the current action (request - response cycle) should probably be available to you in that specific action anyway.

If your aim is to look at the session inside of a template, then I would suggest you explicitly pass a copied version of the session to the template and also set it as a new session.

Controller action:

```
def someAction = Action { implicit request =>
  val updatedSession = request.session.copy(Map("user" -> "Admin")
  Ok(views.html.something("Hello from Scala")(updatedSession)).withSession(updatedSession)
}
```

Template:

```
@(text: String)(implicit session: Session)

<h1>@text</h1>
@session.get("user").map { u=>
  Your role is: @u
}
```

Comment: withSession will set a cookie that will provide the new session on following requests, it does not modify the current RequestHeader object. while I want to modify current session object

Comment: AFAIK the RequestHeader is immutable. It's the state of the request the server receives, i.e. not something you can change while working on the server-side.

Comment: actually my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697371/play-2-2-2-the-session-object-is-only-viewed-after-refresh, just after user login, the user need to refresh the page it can present the user correct message, Can you help me?